# How to receive and display json response in python bottel framework

Tags: python, json, api, rest

I am creating a REST api where i have to process json values as request and response

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/recipes/<name>')
def recipes_list(name):
    return name



run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Run command 1:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/recipes/getstring
```

Output 1:

```
getstring
```

Run command 2:

```
curl http://localhost:80s/getstrinc?p={"s":"get"}
```

Output 2:

```
getstring
```

But expected output is

```
{"s":"get"}
s
get
```

How can i get output in above format